# can i do two times grouping in sql?

Tags: sql, group-by, case, addition, mssql-jdbc

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" = 'DAUGHTER'
          OR   "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" = 'SON'
          OR   "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" = 'SISTER'
          OR   "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" = 'FATHER'
          OR   "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" = 'MOTHER'
          OR   "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" = 'WIFE'
          OR   "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" = 'HUSBAND'
          THEN 'SPOUSE'
          ELSE 'SELF'
          END AS RELATION,

     sum("dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."CLAIM_AMT") AS TOTAL_CLAIM_AMOUNT
FROM
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"
GROUP BY
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION"
```

The result set of the above query is something like the below but i want only two rows 1st adding all the values of "SPOUSE" and 2nd only "SELF" with the value of 1,689,292.0

```
RELATION TOTAL_CLAIM_AMOUNT
-------------------
SPOUSE  121724.0
SPOUSE  2440297.0
SPOUSE  145586.0
SPOUSE  853361.0
SELF    1689292.0
SPOUSE  1.0
SPOUSE  373190.0
SPOUSE  1984198.0
```

I need help in doing that. Please suggest me how do i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your query like this with the outer `select` applying the same group by on same column and you will get the result you want.Also you can use `IN` operator in your `CASE` to shorten the query.

```
 SELECT SUM(TOTAL_CLAIM_AMOUNT) AS TotalClaimAmount, Relation
 FROM
    (
      SELECT
         CASE WHEN "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION" IN ('DAUGHTER','SON','SISTER','FATHER','MOTHER','WIFE','HUSBAND')THEN 'SPOUSE'
              ELSE 'SELF'
          END AS RELATION,
          SUM("dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."CLAIM_AMT") AS TOTAL_CLAIM_AMOUNT
     FROM
        "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"
     GROUP BY
         "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION"
    )As innerData
  GROUP BY RELATION
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. . this is the error msg

Comment: IM extremely sorry Mr. i got the result. Thanks a lot. Thank you very much.